# How to complete the application when pressed buttons Home i Back?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monocross

How to complete the application when pressed buttons Home and Back? Provided that in my memory holds many pictures.
When pressed on the Back button - application restarts... When pressed on the Home button - quit application, but when it restart - does not start Splashstsreen.

Comment: Soooo.... you want to make the "Home" button behave like the "Back" button?

Comment: No, I want to complete the application when I click on these buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete"? It doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: I mean exit application.

Comment: Like some of the responders say, you shouldn't make things that the user doesn't expect. You should map your flow around what the normal flow in android is. There's no "completing" the application. There's no "application".

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see without code but it sounds like your activity is resuming rather then starting from scratch (as it should behave). It sounds like it's behaving correctly in that case. If you insist in wanting your application to truly quit after the back button is clicked perhaps you can override onBackPressed() then have your Activity call its finish() method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's good programming practice to fiddle and interfering with the activities lifecycle. It's the OS responsibility to manage the lifecycle, including pause and finish activities. 
Instead you should use other methods to handle your problem with not showing splash screen, these methods are onResume and maybe also onStart(). Also you should get familiar with the activity lifecycle(link submitted by @ss1271).

Comment: ok, but I do not work "back" button - my game (application) just starts up again!

Answer (score 0):

Press Home will let the activity to enter `onPause()`. however, if you insist to quit the application when press HOME, which is obviously not a good practise, you can do like this:

1. Override `onPause()` and `onBackPressed()`
2. add `finish();` to these methods.

I am sure by adding `finish();` to `onBackPressed()` will quit the app when Back button pressed, but I haven't tried on Home.

Please refer to [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more info.

Comment: After pressing the "Back" - gives the following error:
Android is not responding. Would you like to close it? (Wait/ok)

Comment: could you post some related code? Without code we can't tell you where the problem is :)